# Declaring a shortcut in a google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-shortcuts, manifest, shortcut

I'm trying to learn chrome extensions and develop one aswell. I want to make a keyboard shortcut for user(like PanicButton extension). I couldn't find a good source for this. Can you help me with the code or lead to a source?

for example alert "something" with the combination of "Shift + R"

Comment: See chrome.commands API documentation.

Comment: i will look into that thanks